# Print a variable defined on multiple sets

Tags: ampl

I have defined the variables w in AMPL in the following way:

`var w[F,J,T] binary;`

where F, J and T are sets.
After solving the problem, I would like to print the tables w[f,*,*] for each f in F. What is the command that does this?

If I just write

`display w;`

it returns me the tables w[*,j,*] for each j in J (I guess it's a question of the size of the results).

Thanks to anyone who will answer

Answer (score 0):

By the way, for future reference, the answer is:

`display {f in F} : {j in J, t in T} w[f, j, t];`